# send form data to two pages php in same format

Tags: php, html, forms

I need form data to be sent to two different pages`(a0.php & a1.php)`. I cant use session because I dont have access to `(a1.php)` page.

So now i want some intermediate page where i can access the form data and redirect to another page as form post itself.

**existing**

//front end

```
<form action="a1.php" method="post">
</form>
```

//a1.php

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

**Needed**

//front end

```
<form action="a0.php" method="post">
</form>
```

//a0.php

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST); //access form data here
header("location:a1.php")// pass form post data through redirection 

?>
```

//a1.php

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST); //access form data here also in same format/fashion
?>
```

Note: I dont want to pass parameters in url, in this case, I prefer `POST` over `GET`

Comment: You can send the data through the URL with `header()` in a0.php to a1.php if it is not sensitive data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two different actions on form submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384819/two-different-actions-on-form-submit)

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384819/two-different-actions-on-form-submit

Answer (score 3):

You can use javascript.

`onClick` will fire function that will send the data to first page without refreshing (ajax), and so send to the second page.

```
<form>
<button type=submit" onclick="x()" >
</form>

<script>
function x(){
  //ajax to a1.php
  //send to a2.php
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

On a0.php page

```
<?php
$queryString = http_build_query($_REQUEST);
header("Location: a1.php?" . $queryString );
?>
```

On a1.php

```
<?php
var_dump($_REQUEST);
?>
```

Comment: But I dont want to send it in url, I want to `POST` the variables. because in `a1.php` its `extract($_POST)`

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use ajax.

When you will click submit button, then using jquery you can get the values and post to a page using ajax.

Then the first form will be submitted after the ajax call.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function ajax_call_list()
    {
        var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
        var address = document.getElementById('address').value;

        var vURL = "b.php?name="+name+"&address="+address; 
        jQuery.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",   url: vURL, data: "",    success: function(result)
            {
                if(result)
                {
                        $("#form_submit").submit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<form action="a.php" id="form_submit">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <input type="address" name="address" id="address">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onClick="callAjax()">
</form>
```

I hope it will help.

Thanks

Comment: can I get hidden field values like this?

Comment: Yes, you can get the hidden field values in same way as you get text field values using javascript or jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can include a1.php inside a0.php so that all post variables are available in a1.php too

include('a1.php');

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in the days of jQuery, Angular Js and Ajax, people are forgetting about plain Javascript. Around 2005, I had submitted a php page to itself and to another php page in another Frame. Here is my code:

**JS**

```
function validate() {
    var valid = true;
    if(valid) {
        document.f1.target = "headframe";
        document.f1.action = "page1.php";    // This is the same page
        document.f1.submit();

        document.f1.target = "mainframe";
        document.f1.action = "page2.php";    // Another page
        document.f1.submit();
    }
}
```

It still works perfectly. KISS principle says "Keep it simple, stupid!"