# Get form data in two pages with PHP

Tags: php, forms

I have a simple search form:

```
<form method="get" action="page1.php">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Now I want `$_GET['name']` data in two pages *page1.php* and *page2.php*.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Means you want to submit this form to TWO pages ?

Comment: Yes. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sessions](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp).

Whenever or wherever you get your $_GET['name'], use session to keep it, and then you can use it anywhere.

```
$_SESSION["name"] = $_GET['name'];
```

On every page do this,

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["name"])){
    $name = $_SESSION["name"];
}
```

Comment: So you have two files, on de first file where you do $_GET['name'], you also set a session for it like $_SESSION['name'] = $_GET['name']. so if you need on file2, you simply say $name = $_SESSION['name']...done

Answer (score 0):

You want the user to submit some information to two different php-"pages". I can't figure out if you want to sent this information to these "pages" in parallel (option 1), so at the same time (more or less) or if you just want to have the information to be availible for php-scripts executed after the first one (option 2).

I think **option 2** is the one which is covered by monace19. Maybe you can think about using cookies as well (instead of sessions - but i don't claim this to be a better approach).

If you want to implement **option 1** you may consider using Javascript. To be more precise you can fire two ajax-requests after each other which deliver the data to the php-scripts. But then you should be aware that JS may be blocked...

See [send form data to two pages php in same format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20490331/send-form-data-to-two-pages-php-in-same-format?rq=1) as well!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get `$_GET['name']` in two pages, try this simple solution:

**HTML**

```
<form method="get" action="page1.php/?next_script=page2.php">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

**page1.php**

```
<?php 
    // ...
    header("Location: ". $_GET['next_script'].'?name'=$_GET['name']); // here we go to the page2.php
?>
```

You will get `$_GET['name']` in page2.php as you wanted. (WARNING: if you want to use it in production you should sanitize `$_GET['name']`)